# Proving the image of a set is open.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the image  of the set $S := \{z \in \mathbb{C};\  0 < Re(z) < 3\}$  under the map $w= \frac{1}{z}$ is an open set.

Comment: Have you tried to draw the set $S$?  If you draw the axes (and label the horizontal axis $x$, and the vertical axis $y$) for the complex plane, $S$ is the set formed by looking at region enclosed by the vertical lines $x = 0$ and $x = 3$ (not including either of those lines).  All points (i.e., complex numbers) in this region are in $S$.

Comment: I understand all of that, but I'm not sure how to construct a rigorous proof for this situation.

Comment: I'm confused by what your map is.  Usually we don't represent a map as "$z = \frac{1}{w}$".  Is your map of the form $f: \Bbb C - \{0 \} \to \Bbb C$ such that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: That would be it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image set is $S' := \{w\in \Bbb C : 0 < \operatorname{Re}(1/w) < 3\}$. To show $S'$ is open, we prove $\Bbb C \setminus S'$ is closed. Now $\Bbb C \setminus S'$ is the union of the set $A := \{w\in \Bbb C : \operatorname{Re}(1/w) \le 0\}$ and set $B := \{w\in \Bbb C : \operatorname{Re}(1/w) \ge 3\}$. Since the union of two closed sets is closed, it suffices to show that $A$ and $B$ are closed. To see that $B$ is closed, let $w$ be a limit point of $A$. There exists a sequence $w_n \in B$ such that $w_n \to w$. Then $w_n \neq 0$ for all $n$ and $1/w_n \to 1/w$. So since $\operatorname{Re}(1/w_n) \ge 3$ for all $n$, $\operatorname{Re}(1/w) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \operatorname{Re}(1/w_n) \ge 3$. Hence $w\in B$, and consequently $B$ is closed. By a similar argument, $A$ is closed.

Comment: I think I'm a little confused by the limit argument here. Don't we want $w \in B$, not $w \in A$, in order to show that all of the boundary points of B are in B and is therefore closed?

Comment: @Forest that was a typo, now fixed. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thank so much, I've been having trouble distinguishing the steps needed to prove these types of things but this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Check that $f: \Bbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ given by $f(z) = 1/z$ is a homeomorphism and that $S$ is open.

Comment: I haven't learned anything about homeomorphisms yet so I'm not quite comfortable with this approach.